# GoogleIMA: 1009 The VAST response document is empty

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vast, google-ima, google-ads-api

**THE SITUATION:**

I am trying to display preroll ads videos on my app.

I have two different `adTagUrl`. 
One works fine and the preroll ad is displayed. 
The other doesn't, and I get an **empty VAST response** instead.

I thought there may be something wrong in the code, so I recreate a basic small app taking the code from the [google IMA repo example](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-ima-html5/tree/master/simple).

The results is the same. One work and the other doesn't.

**THE ERROR:**

```
errorCode: 1009
errorMessage: "The VAST response document is empty."
type: "adLoadError"
```

[image: The VAST response document is empty]

**VAST INSPECTOR:**

If I check the VAST ad response using the [Google Video Suite Inspector](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/client-side/vastinspector), both the `adTagUrl` work.

**THE CODE:**

The code is very straightforward, taken from the google IMA example repo:

```
var adsRequest = new google.ima.AdsRequest();
adsRequest.adTagUrl = 'MY_TAG_URL';

adsRequest.linearAdSlotWidth = 640;
adsRequest.linearAdSlotHeight = 400;
adsRequest.nonLinearAdSlotWidth = 640;
adsRequest.nonLinearAdSlotHeight = 150;
adsLoader.requestAds(adsRequest);
```

**THE QUESTION:**

Why am I getting that error?

How it's possible that the adTagUrl works fine in the Vast Inspector, but it doesn't work when I request it from the code?

Comment: VAST servers often apply heuristics to evaluate whether the incoming VAST request is legit. There is a chance that your VAST request was marked as fraudulent and in these cases VAST server usually sends back an empty VAST response. Difficult to say without seeing the tags though.